# Popen works locally but not remotely issue

Tags: python, jenkins, exe, remote-access

I created a python.exe, through pyinstaller, that will open a notepad++ shortcut called notpadplus.Lnk.

When I ran the program locally, the python.exe would open notepad++.
However, when I tell Jenkins to run the python.exe nothing gets opened.

```
subprocess.Popen(os.path(self.JenkinsFolderPath , 'Notepadplus.lnk'))
```

This is the method I call in python to open the shortcut, and in jenkins I use a powershell script to call the python.exe:

```
Start-Process "c:\JenkinsResources\MarinaMain.exe" -ArgumentList "$UserName" -Wait
```

The question i want to know is why Popen doesnt work remotley and the option i have to resolve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Jenkins run the exe in a remote session and popen only works locally which is what i think is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i resolve this was by going to:

Services -> Jenkins Agent -> Log On

Then i would set "This account" to be the current user. After that Popen would work and open anything i needed to use on that current user.